# Why is Excel macro ignoring newly added column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro used to create flash cards, that copies all data in the selected spreadsheet to another spreadsheet, and multiplies the rows in groups of 4. This is so it can be easily mail merged into Word for double-sided printing.
I added a new column of data to the sheet, but when I run the macro, it completely ignores it and only processes the already existent columns.

I'm familiar in C# but not Visual Basic, which means that while I can understand the gist of the macro, I can't edit or add to the code without tediously looking up the use of every keyword in the documentation. (I received the macro from a VB programmer.)

I'm not sure which part of the code is needed to fix this problem, so here's the whole sub:
(I renamed some of the variables to make the code easier to read. Eg j => ixLoop)

```
Sub a()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet, shttarget As Worksheet
Dim arrData As Variant
Set shtSouce = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
arrData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set shttarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
For ixBound = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2) 'i
    shttarget.Range("A1").Offset(0, ixBound - 1) = arrData(1, ixBound)
Next ixBound
quarterOfUBound = Int(UBound(arrData, 1) / 4) 'n
remOfQuarterOfUBound = UBound(arrData, 1) Mod 4 'm
counter = 0 'k
For ixLoop = 1 To quarterOfUBound 'j
    For ixLoop2 = counter + 1 To counter + 4 'r
        For ixBound = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            shttarget.Range("A1").Offset(ixLoop2 + counter, ixBound - 1) = arrData(ixLoop2 + 1, ixBound)
        Next ixBound
    Next ixLoop2
    For ixLoop2 = 2 To 4 Step 2
        For ixBound = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            shttarget.Range("A1").Offset(ixLoop * 4 + counter + ixLoop2 - 1, ixBound - 1) = arrData(ixLoop2 + 1 + counter, ixBound)
        Next ixBound
    Next ixLoop2
    For ixLoop2 = 1 To 3 Step 2
        For ixBound = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            shttarget.Range("A1").Offset(ixLoop * 4 + counter + ixLoop2 + 1, ixBound - 1) = arrData(ixLoop2 + 1 + counter, ixBound)
        Next ixBound
    Next ixLoop2
    counter = counter + 4
Next ixLoop


End Sub
```

What code needs to be changed or added to enable the new column to be included in the process?

Comment: Where is the location of the 'new' column in the source sheet?

Comment: It seems that the processing bases on `arrData`which is read in the line `arrData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value`. Add a statement `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address` and check the result in the immediate Window (Ctrl+G). Does it contain your new column? Do you have any empty column between `A` and your new column?

Comment: The 'new' column was added in the middle of the columns ie between D and F, but I tried adding it in other places as well, without results.

Comment: @FunThomas I added `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address` and I get Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference